# How can this English sentence be translated into a logical expression? ( Translating " unless")

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall unless you are older than 16 years old.

Let:

- $P$ stands for *"you can ride the roller coaster"*
- $Q$ stands for *"you are under 4 feet tall"*
- $R$ stands for *"you are older than 16 years old"*

Is this logical expression correctly translated?

$$P \rightarrow (Q \wedge R)$$

Comment: $ (q \land \lnot r) \Rightarrow p $

Comment: You can pretty much see that your answer must be wrong because it translates as "if you cannot ride the roller coaster then. . .", whereas the given statement says something like "if. . . then you cannot rider the roller coaster."  In other words you have made the *converse error*.

Comment: $P$ must stand for '*you* **can** *ride the roller coaster*'..

Comment: As you can see from your source : Kenneth Rosen, *Discrete mathematics and its applications* (7th ed), page 17, the answer is : $(q ∧¬r) → ¬p$.

Comment: My answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4413667/21813).

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion of $P\to (Q \wedge R)$ would say that in order to ride the roller coaster you must be at least $4$ feet tall and you must me at least $16$ years old.  But I would say the meaning of the given sentence is that you need to satisfy one of the age and height conditions, not both.

I think the sentence means: In order to ride the roller coaster, you must be at least $4$ feet tall, or you must be over $16$ years old.

Symbolically (using your $P, Q, R$), this would be $P\to (Q\vee R)$. In contrapositive form (which would tell you what keeps you from riding the roller coaster: $(\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\to \neg R$.  (If you are under 4 feet tall and younger than $16$, then you can't ride the roller coaster).

Answer (score 3):

**(1) 'Unless' statements**:

There are some known [strategies](http://www.manhattanlsat.com/blog/2013/09/26/unless-statements-in-2-minutes/) to transform '**unless**' clauses into conditional statements. The most common one seems to be directly translate them using '**if not**':

- *I'm not coming to the party unless Sylvia comes.*
- *I wouldn't eat that food unless I was really hungry.*

The examples above can be respectively translated as follows:

- *If Sylvia is not coming to the party, neither am I.*
- *If am not really hungry I wouldn't eat that food.*

Alternatively, we can use their (reverse) contrapositive forms:

- *I am coming to the party if Sylvia is.*
- *I would eat that food If was really hungry.*

**(2) Your Answer**:

Consider the English sentence

> You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall unless you are older than 16 years old.

Following the above reasoning we have:

> If you are not older than 16 years, then you cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall.

which is the same as:

> If you are not older than 16 years, then if you are under 4 feet tall you cannot ride the roller coaster.

Now let:

- $P$ stand for '*you can ride the roller coaster*'
- $Q$ stand for '*you are under 4 feet tall*'
- $R$ stand for '*you are older than 16 years old*'

The answer you are looking for is

$$ \neg R \to (Q \to \neg P).$$

Comment: Or ( q-> -r ) -> p is it true ?

Comment: @user189029 Hint: Have a look at their truth-tables, are their both logically equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: let suppose 
q= You can ride the roller coaster;
p= you are older than 16 years old;
r= you are under 4 feet tall;
There is two states of “q if p” and “q if r”;
Because 
•   q unless p :: (the statement is as )
You can ride the roller coaster unless you are not older than 16 years old;
•   q, if r :: (the statement is as)
You can ride the roller coaster unless you are under 4 feet tall;

•   These two statements have same conclusion that is “you can ride a roller coaster” and the hypothesis are two.
So these two conclusions may be simplify in one statement as:
“You can ride the roller coaster, if you are under 4 feet tall and you are not older than 16 years old”

Then in this statement there is the (q, if p) form of implication and p which is the hypothesis has the operator “and” .So, the expression is 
Hypothesis -> conclusion as:
                (r ^ ~p) -> ~q
Where ~p means: you are not older than 16 years old” and 
~q means: You cannot ride the roller coaster.

Comment: please make use of MathJax

Answer (score 0):

No, because $P\implies Q\land R$ actually means that **You must be under 4 feet tall and older than 16 to ride the roller coaster** which is not true. You can be under 4 feet tall and more than 16 years old and still ride the roller coaster. The sentence of the question is equivalent to:

> If you are more than 16 years old **or** more than 4 feet tall **or both**, you can ride the roller coaster.

which is $$(\lnot Q\lor R)\implies P$$so, the *if-else-then* statements always work.

Another way to tackle these sort of problem is the truth table:

$$
\begin{matrix}
Q&R&P
\\0&0&1
\\0&1&1
\\1&0&0
\\1&1&1
\end{matrix}
$$