# How can this sentence be translated into a logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> "You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under $4$ ft tall, unless you are older than $16$ years old."

$q$: ride the coaster

$r$: under $4$ft tall

$s$: older than $16$

It was my understanding that "unless" translates to "if not" therefore I came up with:
$$\neg s \to (r \to \neg q).$$

However, the book gives this as the answer:

$$(r \land \neg s) \to \neg q.$$

Which makes sense, however I don't see where the "and" comes from. Does "unless" mean something different in this context?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003705/174538

Answer (score 1):

You are right, and so is the book.   The answers are equivalent.

$$\neg s \to (r \to \neg q) \iff (\neg s\wedge r)\to \neg q$$

In either case the only way to *guarantee* $\neg q$ holds is if both $\neg s$ and $r$ hold.

---

This is called the rule of **Exportation**.

$$P\to (Q\to R) \dashv\vdash (P\wedge Q)\to R$$